# How to include custom data into vis.js timeline item

Tags: javascript, timeline, vis.js, vis.js-timeline, vis-timeline

I have been using vis.js timeline to keep items in a time order.

I use the following to add timeline items :

```
timeline_items.add({
    id              : entity_id + uuidv4(),
    group           : "timeline_video_group_id",
    start           : start_date,
    end             : end_date,
    content         : "<img src='" + element_src_link + "'></img>",
    className       : 'imagecontainer'
});
```

However, I cannot add any custom data into this add function.

How may I add custom data, so it may hold information such as entity-uuid=xxxx inside the div below ?

```
<div class="vis-item vis-range imagecontainer vis-editable" style="transform...">
  <div class="vis-item-overflow">
    <div class="vis-item-content" style="transform: translateX(0px);">
      <img src="image_src">
    </div>
    <div class="vis-item-visible-frame">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't u just add your information in your content property directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the content to the full HTML you would like, including an image and text, then store this in the DataSet. The vis.js example named 'Custom Styling' [here](https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/examples/timeline/styling/customCss.html) uses this approach.

```js
content: '<div>Mail from boss</div><img src="../resources/img/mail-icon.png" style="width:32px; height:32px;">',
```

Alternatively you could add custom data to the items in the DataSet, then use the template feature described in the documentation [here](https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/docs/timeline/#Templates) to construct the HTML. This is the approach I would use.

An example of a template is incorporated into the post below and also at https://jsfiddle.net/xm95u40f/. The example adds a property named `imageColor` to each item in the DataSet, this is used in combination with the text from the content to display the item. You could store and use your `entity-uuid` value in a similar way.

```js
// DOM element where the Timeline will be attached
var container = document.getElementById("visualization");

// Create a DataSet (allows two way data-binding)
var items = new vis.DataSet();

items.add([
  { id: 1, content: "item 1", start: "2021-12-21", end: "2021-12-23", imageColor: "0000FF" },
  { id: 2, content: "item 2", start: "2021-12-14", end: "2021-12-17", imageColor: "FFFFFF" },
  { id: 3, content: "item 3", start: "2021-12-18", end: "2021-12-20", imageColor: "0000FF" },
  { id: 4, content: "item 4", start: "2021-12-16", end: "2021-12-21", imageColor: "FFFFFF" },
  { id: 5, content: "item 5", start: "2021-12-25", end: "2021-12-27", imageColor: "000000" },
  { id: 6, content: "item 6", start: "2021-12-27", end: "2021-12-28", imageColor: "008000" },
]);

// Configuration for the Timeline
var options = {
  // Define a template function which constructions the HTML for each item
  template: function (item, element, data) {
    var html = "<img class='timeline-image' src='https://via.placeholder.com/40/" + item.imageColor + "'><div>" + item.content + "</div>"
    return html;
  },
  // Using a template requires any attributes to be whitelisted to prevent XSS
  // More details at https://github.com/visjs/vis-timeline/pull/1010
  xss: {
    disabled: false,
    filterOptions: {
      whiteList: { img: ['src', 'class'], div: 'class' }
    },
  },
};

// Create a Timeline
var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options);
```

```css
body,
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* 
Timeline image is defined with a fixed height and width.
When the timeline loads it determines the size of items
then uses this to place them, as the images won't be 
loaded at this point the size must be set to ensure the 
spacing is correct
*/
.timeline-image {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/standalone/umd/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://visjs.github.io/vis-timeline/styles/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="visualization"></div>
```